# Format Numbers and Dates in dust.js (linkedin-fork)

Tags: javascript, dust.js, client-side-templating

How can i format numbers, currency or date values within a dust.js template?

**Data:**

```
{
today: 'Wed Apr 03 2013 10:23:34 GMT+0200 (CEST)'
}
```

**Template:**

```
<p>Today: {today} </p>
```

**Like this way: (with moment.js)**

```
<p>Today: {moment(today).format('dd.MM.YYYY')}</p>
```

**Or round some price-values***

Data:
    { price: 56.23423425 }

Template:

Price: {price.toFixed(2)}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably going to need to write a helper.  Details on how to write a helper can be found here:

- https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Writing_a_dust_helper

Your template for a Date string would look like this:

```
<p>Today: {@formatDate value="{today}"/}</p>
```

Your helper would be something like this:

```
dust.helpers.formatDate = function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var value = dust.helpers.tap(params.value, chunk, context),
        timestamp,
        month,
        date,
        year;

    timestamp = new Date(value);
    month = timestamp.getMonth() + 1;
    date = timestamp.getDate();
    year = timestamp.getFullYear();

    return chunk.write(date + '.' + month + '.' + year);
};
```

You would want to add in the piece to get the leading zero in front of the month or date as well.

Answer (score 3):

For people that need to do this for a nodeJs application, here's a nice KrakenJS example:

https://github.com/lmarkus/Kraken_Example_Date_Format_Helper

It uses Moment.js to avoid reinventing the wheel on date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a filter to use moment. put sth like this:
    dust.filters.formatDate = (value) => moment.utc(value).format('l H:mm');
where proper in your script.
then in your html, just put | beside your value:
    {date|formatDate}